# which maven repository after jcenter died?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

so yesterday I updated my android studio to the newest version (4.2) and after building my project I got this warning

```
Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
Currently detected usages in: root project 'Personal Dictionary', project ':app'
```

so what repository should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where your dependencies are hosted. Not all libraries are yet migrated off `jcenter` yet. Generally, `mavenCentral` seems to be the most popular repo.

You can comment out `jcenter` in your build.gradle file, invoke gradle build with `--refresh-dependencies` command line option and see if the build is failing somewhere. You can use [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) service to try to find other repos for your dependencies.

If there are still dependencies that are only in jcenter, you can restrict gradle to only use that specific dependency from that repo:

```
jcenter() {
    content {
        includeModule("<group id>", "<artifact id>")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your full and short answer, the warning disapeard

Answer (score 0):

To add to laalto's excellent answer, if you have a simple project you can likely replace the two instances of:

```
jcenter()
```

with

```
mavenCentral()
```

in your project's `build.gradle` file. Recompile/build your project after making the changes to see if it builds successfully.