# migrating to mavenCentral from jcenter

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jcenter, maven-central

Android studio gave me a couple of warnings that I need to migrate away from jcenter(). I am new to android developing so started looking online for replacements. I found an article that said that I should move to MavenCentral. I don't know if this is a good replacement. What do you guys think?

I tried to build my project with jcenter() replaced by mavenCentral() but it won't build because I need:

> ```
> implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
> ```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: See this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460472/which-maven-repository-after-jcenter-died

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switch back to jcenter and keep using jcenter for the time being and if possible try to find replacement for that if its not appearing in other repo. That's what I've been doing